# NAV-LINK - test for user input before redirect?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make sure that the user has made a selection from a dropdown before they are able to redirect to another page via a NAV-LINK in an `<li>`. Is it possible to test for the users selection first and prevent the redirection by keeping them on the page?

I'm able to fire the `onclick` event but I'm failing to stop the re-direction. Can any please help me?

```
<script>
function testInput(){ 
    alert("please make a selection..");
}
</script>
```

.

```
  <li class="nav-item" onclick="testInput()">
      <a class="nav-link" href="adduser.php">
          <span data-feather="Add User"></span>
          Add User
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples. I have and I still get re-directed,  After re-reading my original question I think I misstated what I was trying to do. If the user has selected an option from a SELECT box, I save that value in a $_SESSION() variable. So reading directly from the SELECT isn't necessary. Can I check if the $_SESSION variable is not blank when clicking on a LIST item <li? If the $_SESSION variable is blank then I DO NOT want the page to re-direct. Hopefully that clears up the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="adduser.php" onclick="testInput(event)">
      <span data-feather="Add User"></span>
      Add User
    </a>
  </li>

<select id = "drop-down">
    <option value ="none" disabled selected>Select an option</option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
</select>

<script>
function testInput(e){
    if (document.getElementById("drop-down").value == "none") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("please make a selection..");
    }}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking whether the dropdown has been changed or not;

```
document.getElementById('id_of_your_dropdown').addEventListener('change', () => {
     place your code here which redirects to the other page
})
```

Here is an example which prints some text to the console when some option is selected from the dropdown;

```js
document.getElementById('dd').addEventListener('change', () => {
console.log('some value selected');
})
```

```html
<select id='dd'>
  <option>first</option>
  <option>second</option>
  <option>third</option>
  <option>forth</option>
</select>
```